# Is RabbitMQ's message backing store global?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am studying RabbitMQ; how it works.

According to the documents about its internal, the message store keeps the message contents and the queues keep only the indices to the messages.

So when the same message is routed to the multiple queues, it does not duplicate the message content but rather store it only once keeping the reference (message id) to the message in those queues.

Then what if a message is enqueued into the multiple queues that belong to the different machines? Will the message be stored only at one of the machines?

The question can be rephrased as follows: is the messages backing store global across cluster machines or local for each machine?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ stores the messages using a custom database, the location is usually:

`/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@hostname/queues/`

> Then what if a message is enqueued into the multiple queues that
>   belong to the different machines?

When you setup a cluster the queue is visible across the cluster but the owner is always one node, so each operation is redirect to the queue owner.

If the node is down the queue is marked as `down` and you can't access to the queue.

> is the messages backing store global across cluster machines or local
>   for each machine?

by default each node contains the its queues data.

If you enable the ha policies ( https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html ) the messages are mirrored to the other nodes, if the owner gets down the queue change the ownership and the messages are available

Comment: So...  when a message is enqueued into the multiple queues (that are not ha) that belong to the different machines, will the message be stored only at one of the machines?
I guess you mean Yes. Am I right?

Comment: No, if a message is enqueued into multiple queues it will stored on the queues owner. Suppose you have 3 queues in 3 machines the message will be stored in 3 different machines

Comment: I got it. The messages are locally replicated at the owner machines.